# How do I sum text values like numbers in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a cell that is made up of multiple countries e.g. America, Japan, Korea, China, UK, about 30 of them. I would like to assign a score to each country e.g. America = 1, Japan = 2,... and then sum them up. How do I go about this?

Comment: Put your score in a second column and run sum on it.

Comment: @KCM could you please share some sample data with us!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume cell `A1` : `America, Japan, Korea, China, UK`

and, assign country score : America=1, Japan=2, Korea=3, China=4 and UK=5

In `B1`, enter array (CSE) formula :

```
=SUM(0+VLOOKUP(T(IF(1,FILTERXML("<a><a>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,", ","</a><a>")&"</a></a>","a/a"))),{"America",1;"Japan",2;"Korea",3;"China",4;"UK",5},2,0))
```

`B1` will return the sum up country score result of `15`

Edit :

This formula used a FILTERXML function which is available since Excel 2013 or after.

Array formula to be confirmed by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> 3 keystrokes together instead of just ENTER.

Comment: @Alex ,, could you please specify that,, in which Excel version this formula executes?

Comment: @RajeshS I just edited the answer to fix some obvious errors, didn't evaluate it for content. OP seems happy though!

Comment: @bosco_yip could you please share some sample data used with the show formula coz this is web related function !!

Comment: @Rajesh, please go to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-formula and in the topping line Searching box, enter : "FILTERXML", that will return some posts replies in using of the Filterxml  function